# Autocomplete activity cannot be launched until fragment is enabled

Tags: java, android, maps

I am using google map Place API. Using google's build-in UI (AutoCompleteFragment) when I click on the fragment for the first time I get the UI but when I click on the fragment second time I get the error

**Autocomplete activity cannot be launched until fragment is enabled.**

secondly when I click on the place which I searched then noting happen below is the code. I am calling it onCreate method

```
 private void placeAutoComplete(){

        if (!Places.isInitialized()) {
            Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.google_api_key));
        }


        // Initialize the AutocompleteSupportFragment.
        AutocompleteSupportFragment autocompleteFragment = (AutocompleteSupportFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment);


        ImageView searchIcon = (ImageView)((LinearLayout)autocompleteFragment.getView()).getChildAt(0);
        searchIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        autocompleteFragment.setHint(getString(R.string.whereToToday));

// Specify the types of place data to return.
        autocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME , Place.Field.LAT_LNG));
        Log.e(TAG, "Before entering into things: "  );
// Set up a PlaceSelectionListener to handle the response.
        autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
                // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
                Log.e(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName() + ", " + place.getId());
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "we here baby", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                LatLng coordinate =   place.getLatLng();
                CameraUpdate location = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinate, 16);
                mMap.animateCamera(location , 1500 , null);
                Marker mMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(coordinate));



            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Status status) {
                // TODO: Handle the error.
                Log.e(TAG, "An error occurred: " + status);

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });




    }
```

this portion of the code is not working at all after selecting the place

```
 autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
                    // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
                    Log.e(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName() + ", " + place.getId());
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "we here baby", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    LatLng coordinate =   place.getLatLng();
                    CameraUpdate location = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinate, 16);
                    mMap.animateCamera(location , 1500 , null);
                    Marker mMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(coordinate));
                }
                @Override
                public void onError(Status status) {
                    // TODO: Handle the error.
                    Log.e(TAG, "An error occurred: " + status);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:elevation="@dimen/elevation"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"

        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/roundness"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/nav_light_black"
                android:padding="14dp"
                android:id="@+id/navigationView"
                >

            </ImageView>

           <!-- <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/navigationView"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:hint="Where to today?"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:id="@+id/whereTo"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"

                android:textColor="@color/colorLighterBlack"
                android:textSize="@dimen/fontForWhereTo"

                >

            </TextView>-->

            <fragment android:id="@+id/autocomplete_fragment"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/navigationView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:name="com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteSupportFragment"
                />

        </RelativeLayout>


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity" />



    <Button
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:id="@+id/backToCurrentLocation"
        ></Button>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you please place your fragment xml too ?

Comment: I have updated my question with XML

Comment: this is written in google docs   If you are using the Autocomplete fragment, and need to override onActivityResult, you must call super.onActivityResult, otherwise the fragment will not function properly.  try this link too https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete.

Comment: thanks alot.. it solved my problem

Comment: great u welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removing onActivityResult method solved my problem and if you want to use the onActivityResult in your activity then according to google doc

**If you are using the Autocomplete fragment, and need to override onActivityResult, you must call super.onActivityResult, otherwise the fragment will not function properly.**

https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete